# How Do i Use Regex To Replace the - in this date with /

Tags: regex, text, notepad++

I have lines of Data as below

,NULL,1-035-137,8,,NULL,----,NULL,NULL,2017-04-20 13:43:25,2017-04-20 13:43:25,2017-04-20 13:43:25,NULL,

I need to replace the - with / using regex in notepad++

i can select it using \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} is it possible to replace just the "-"?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**capturing groups**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html):

*Find What*: `(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})`
*Replace With*: `$1/$2/$3`

Here, `(...)` define numbered capturing groups that you reference with `$n` [**backreferences**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html). Note that for safer matching, you may add word boundaries around the pattern - `\b(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\b`.

[image]